# Gibberish text in JavaFX Label

Tags: javafx

I have a localized JavaFX application and this is happening to one user, but something similar is reported from other users from time to time:

[image]

As you can see from the image, the application is localized correctly (buttons, table headers..) but the text in the middle of the table (left) is gibberish, it's a simple `Label` styled through css. On the right the same app version running on my computer where everything is fine.

The application runs on a bundled jlinked JDK 11.0.8. I tested it on Linux, Windows and Mac and I cannot reproduce.

Any idea of what could cause this behavior or what I can do to investigate it?
Thanks

Comment: Where have you written the original line? An FXML file? The CSS style-class? A Java class?

Comment: Text is read from a properties file and used to create the Label. Here https://github.com/torakiki/pdfsam/blob/6417453638a6102fd6d5a228c25cff35cda0a586/pdfsam-fx/src/main/java/org/pdfsam/ui/selection/multiple/SelectionTable.java#L109